# How: Insert pair into multimap, with one of the types being abstract?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, polymorphism, abstract-class

For example:

```
abstract class goal
class priority
class childgoal

multimap<priority, goal> mm;
mm.insert(make_pair(priority(), childgoal());
```

I get the error:

```
cannot declare field 'std::pair<priority, goal>::second'
to be of abstract type 'goal'
```

If I remember correctly, Pair uses the default constructor to create second before assigning, which is the cause of the distress. I may be incorrect, but it would explain the error.

How do I get around this... how can i accomplish inserting into a multimap (or probably map for that matter) when one of the types is abstract?

Comment: You can't do anything with instances of abstract types; ever. They cannot exist. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a map of pointers:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class Base { };
class Derived1 : public Base { };
class Derived2 : public Base { };

typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> MyPtr;
typedef std::multimap<Key, MyPtr> MyMap;

int main()
{
  MyMap m { { Key(1), MyPtr(new Derived1) }, { Key(2), MyPtr(new Derived2) } };
}
```

Uniform initialization syntax requires C++11 support. In older versions, you can insert instead:

```
m.insert(MyMap::value_type(Key(1), MyPtr(new Derived1)));
```

If nobody else needs the mapped objects, you might get away with a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead. A simple matter of changing the typedef.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm generally trying to keep things as simple as possible, therefore I would like to avoid even smart pointers, however if there is no other solution, this one seems fairly good.

Luckily I do have the option of using C++11.

Comment: Well, the mapped type of a map is fixed, so your original question "can I have a map with variable mapped type" can only be answered "no". The next best thing is a polymorphic pointer-to-base; and since we don't use pointers in C++, I went for `shared_ptr`, optionally `unique_ptr`...

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. You can't assign a child object to an object of it's parent type if it is abstract, unless it is merely a pointer.

Why the heck does it even allow me to use the abstract type as a type for map? Considering it's impossible to use. (ie. map<type, abstract> without pointer)

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell: Strictly speaking it wouldn't change anything if you couldn't; but it just doesn't detect that for you in the template parameter. I *think* a conforming implementation is allowed to, if it wanted to use some clever template magic. But really there's little point since, as you say, it would be impossible to use anyway.

Comment: I think I understand. It seems to me that the moral of the story is to use pointers when dealing with abstract types.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell: Well, think about it: the template is just... a template. It just has that one type parameter, and you can fill in whatever you want. It would be an enormously *bigger* effort to add checks as to whether the type is valid (e.g. instantiable). There's simply no reason for the language to add such arbitrary restrictions. After all, the *type* `map<K,V>` is a valid type no matter what `V` is. You might only want to use that *type*, and never instantiate it. Or you might only want to instantiate an empty map. Who's to tell you that you aren't allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to use polymorphism (since you want to put a derived class were only a base class is expected).

But everytime you want to use polymorphism, you should have the automatism to use pointer-to-base (reference-to-base also works if I recall correctly). Assuming that childgoal publicly inherits from goal, following statements are true :

- *childgoal* is-a *goal*
- a pointer to *goal* can point to *goal* or to *childgoal* (or to any derived class)
- but a *goal* instance **is-NOT-a** *childgoal*

So basically, if you were able to transtype your childgoal into a goal (*that is not possible here since you try to instantiate an abstract class*), you would get rid of all the extra-members present in childgoal, thus loosing your original object. I think this was not your intent.

If you are afraid about the memory management issue that would arise with classic pointers, you could consider using shared_pointers here :

```
abstract class goal;
class priority;
class childgoal : public goal;

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<goal> goalPtr; //sadly I think std::tr1 is not a multiplatform namespace 

multimap<priority, goalPtr> mm;
goalPtr tmpChildGoal(new childgoal()); //always use named shared pointer !
mm.insert(make_pair(priority(), tmpChildGoal);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation. It helped clear some cobwebs for C++. The other answer given is more precisely the answer to my question, but your answer definitely helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply said:
abstract classes can only be used as pointers or references.
If you need a container of a polymorphic instance of your class you need to store a pointer or, better, a smart pointer, possibly a unique_ptr.